# How do I get a cross-join with power query to "remember" values associated with it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Let's say you have a basic Excel cross-query. You have two lists:

```
A
B
C
```

and

```
X
Y
```

You cross join them (Cartesian join them), and get the following table:

```
A - X
A - Y
B - X
B - Y
C - X
C - Y
```

Now, let's assign values to each of these numbers:

```
A - X - 1
A - Y - 2
B - X - 3
B - Y - 4
C - X - 5
C - Y - 6
```

Now, I want to add a new item to the list - Z

My lists are now

```
A
B
C
```

and

```
X
Y
Z
```

and my cross join is now:

```
A - X
A - Y
A - Z
B - X
B - Y
B - Z
C - X
C - Y
C - Z
```

However, here's where the issue comes in. After I've done this, these are my values:

```
A - X - 1
A - Y - 2
A - Z - 3
B - X - 4
B - Y - 5
B - Z
C - X
C - Y
C - Z - 6
```

No no no, this is all wrong.

I'm currently working around this by pasting the value over before I refresh the table, then running an index-match from the new table to the old table to populate the data over. But I imagine that there has to be a better way.

How can I get my cross joins to remember their data, and keep them fixed?

Example expected result:

```
A - X - 1
A - Y - 2
A - Z
B - X - 3
B - Y - 4
B - Z
C - X - 5
C - Y - 6
C - Z
```

OS: Windows 10
Version: Excel 365

```
let
    Source = TableA,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Lab Name", each LabNames),
    #"Expanded Lab Name" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Lab Name", {"Lab Abbrv"}, {"Lab Abbrv"})
in
    #"Expanded Lab Name"
```

Comment: How exactly are you doing the cross join ?

Comment: With power query. You take the table "Suits", add a custom column, and add the table "Numbers", assuming you've loaded both into the data model. This will create the cross join "Deck of cards"

Comment: [Edit] your post to include your queries

Comment: How do  "Suits" and "Numbers" relate to your question?

Comment: @Olly - it's a two item cross join - they don't get much simpler than that.

Comment: @Selkie Whilst I could try to guess at how you're joining, and assigning the 'values'... But it would help us both much more if I could see your actual queries, rather than guessing / assuming. Not sure what the benefit is to you of not posting your code.

Comment: Values are manually added in post-query